# Will Postgres ON DELETE CASCADE fire ON DELETE triggers on subsequent tables?

Tags: function, postgresql, triggers

Will ON DELETE CASCADE fire ON DELETE triggers on subsequent tables?

I have three tables, results, m_int, and row count. M_int is related to results with a FK. Results has ON DELETE CASCADE set and m_int has a trigger for BEFORE DELETE. Rowcount keeps track of how many rows are in use in m_int and by which user.

My problem is that when I remove a row from results, I want the DELETE CASCADE fire the trigger on m_int. Any ideas? I spent all morning reading documentation and can't find an answer.

```
peri=> \d results
                          Table "public.results"
  Column   |  Type   |                      Modifiers                      
-----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------
 result_id | integer | not null default nextval('result_id_seq'::regclass)
 trial__id | integer | not null
 title     | text    | 
Indexes:
    "results_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (result_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "m_int" CONSTRAINT "m_int_result__id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (result__id) REFERENCES results(result_id) ON DELETE CASCADE

peri=> \d m_int
                               Table "public.m_int"
   Column   |  Type   |                         Modifiers                          
------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------
 metric__id | integer | not null
 result__id | integer | not null
 value      | integer | not null
 m_value_id | bigint  | not null default nextval('m_int_m_value_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "m_int_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (m_value_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "m_int_metric__id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (metric__id) REFERENCES metrics(metric_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "m_int_result__id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (result__id) REFERENCES results(result_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Triggers:
    addrows_m_int AFTER INSERT ON m_int FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_rows_m_int()
    remrows_m_int BEFORE DELETE ON m_int FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE rem_rows_m_int()

peri=> \d rowcount
     Table "public.rowcount"
   Column   |  Type   | Modifiers 
------------+---------+-----------
 user__id   | integer | not null
 table_name | text    | not null
 total_rows | bigint  | 
Indexes:
    "rowcount_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user__id, table_name)
```

Comment: I would consider it a major bug if the trigger was not fired

Comment: I think I see what is going on. My trigger requires an OLD.m_value_id which is present on the m_int table, but not on the restults table. When a delete is sent to results, the cascade delete will not have an OLD.m_value_id and so the trigger won't work. It may be firing, but I get no results. I will try to work out how best to decrement my rowcount table another way.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, the funny thing is that today I read the following about MySQL: "MySQL triggers are also not activated by cascading updates and deletes even when caused by a SQL statement (this is against the standard)"

Comment: @strkol: MySQL has a lot of features that are broken or were never implemented completely. Taking MySQL as a reference for how a relational DBMS should work is a bad idea.

Comment: Instead of showing the table definitions, you should show us your trigger definitions. My guess is that you an error in your trigger.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes absolutely correct, but it's funny that after so many years it's still broken

Comment: @strkol: that doesn't surprise me a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The Manual for [CREATE TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html) will tell you:

> In addition, when the data in the referenced columns is changed, certain actions are performed on the data in this table's columns. The ON DELETE clause specifies the action to perform when a referenced row in the referenced table is being deleted. [...]

So yes, deleting in `results` will also delete in `m_int`. 
Of course this does not mean, that deleting in `m_int` does delete anything in `results`. 
And what your additional triggers `add_rows_m_int` and `rem_rows_m_int` do or prevent - we don't know.